# Using GIT to push changes in an environment that didn't get the source from a checkout

Tags: windows, linux, git

I have been using git on my windows box to track a project I am working on alone. I had to copy the files to a linux box. I made substantial edits to the source on the linux box to get it working w/some components also on the linux box. How can I "properly" push the newly edited source on the linux box to the tree on github now?

I tried copying the root of the project on the linux box to my windows machine and did a "git add *" on the windows box at the root, but **"git status" makes it look like all the files would be seen as "new", which I do not want.** How can I do this without git thinking they're all new files, and instead modified files, as if I had performed all the edits on the windows machine as in the past.

I would accept any answer that gets it done this one time (script, series of git commands, etc).

**Also**, is the correct way to do this in the future to checkout first on the remote box and then perform edits?

*Note:* I haven't committed anything to the tree yet. Just the aforementioned copy to the windows machine and then a "git add *" on the windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you have the same git repo on both machines, but they're independend. If it is so, you can use patch to share changes, see here http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git

Another way might be, if there is a network connection between the machines, and access to the "other" git repository might be possible, you can just pull those changes. See http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html

If none applies, please provide more information, why this won't work.